# Double sums of vectors in a Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a Banach space of infinite dimension (you can assume that $E=c_0$ if it is necessary), let $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of scalars and let $(z_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of vectors in $E$.
Suppose that the following four series are convergent
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i\;,
\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_k\;, 
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_iz_k\right), \mbox{ and }
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i\right)z_k.$$

> **Question:**
>   Does the following equality holds? 
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_iz_k\right)=
> \sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i\right)z_k.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\alpha=\sum_i\alpha_i$, $z=\sum_kz_k$.  Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha_iz_k\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left(\alpha_i\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_k\right)\right)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_iz=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\alpha_i\right)z=\alpha z$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i\right)z_k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha z_k=\alpha\sum_{k=1}^\infty z_k=\alpha z.$$

Comment: Awesome, but I think I wanted to post this question instead. 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746290